# robot framework update output field automatically for all tests when a subset is validated

Tags: robotframework

Good morning,

I've got a directory with hundreds of robot tests, and unfortunately the format of one field will change, not the way of calculating this data.

I'd need to be able to valide for 1 or 2 interfaces that my output is correct, but I don't want to spend hours substituting the same thing for all my tests.

I can try to script it with bash, but it will not be optimal...

Do you think there is a way for robot to automatically validate the data for all the tests once I give the permission to do it?

My output is in JSON... I don't know if it helps.

example: we had before TOTO and now we have: TOTO2017-06-20T13:04:00

Thanks a lot.
Regards,
Thomas

Comment: can you give an example of format change? so that we get a clear idea about it

Comment: Exemple added. :)

Comment: @bryanoakley do you think it's feasible?

Comment: sorry for late reply, but I am still not clear about the problem statement!  how was "TOTO" declared? is it not a variable? how is it substituted in tests? because if it is a variable and used across all files, you change at one place and it reflects everywhere automatically!

Comment: Sorry, actually TOTO is 4 alphanumeric randomly returned by the process. So actually, I have the field that was previously 4an and is now much bigger. I found a way to not check the data coming after TOTO using a wildcard creating a new keyword. It works well. But is there a native feature in robot framework that would ease the validation without adding a new keyword? Thanks a lot. Regards.

Comment: ahh, not sure! lets wait for Bryan's reply :)